# crontab suggested error ：/bin/sh .backup.sh no such file or directory

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I use the command `crontab -e` to execute a shell script at regular intervals.

But something wrong with it.

The shell script is located in  `/opt/oneinstack/oneinstack`，so my crontab is :

> 0 1 * * * cd /opt/oneinstack/oneinstack;./backup.sh >> /data/back.log
>   2>&1 &

The permission for the backup.sh file is 755.

The user using the `crontab -e` command is **root**

Message in /data/back.log is `/bin/sh no such file or directory .`Just like the title.

Manual execution the `backup.sh` is no problem.

What's wrong with it? And how can I fixed it?

Expect someone to help me.Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Why do you change directory btw. You can execute the script via full path `/opt/oneinstack/oneinstack/backup.sh`

Comment: @Ugur I tried that, but it still does not work, and `backup.sh` loads some external configuration files

Comment: One more thing. Try changing `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` on the top of the `backup.sh` file. When you run normally, that `/bin/sh` line can actually be ignored, and the script is executed with your SHELL. Of course make sure /bin/sh  and /bin/bash exist.

Comment: @biocyberman，thank you!And [#comment73786598](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43361551/crontab-suggested-error-bin-sh-backup-sh-no-such-file-or-directory#comment73786598_43361754) 。The reason for my carelessness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the following before the crontab list. For example, if this line is at the top:

```
0 1 * * * cd /opt/oneinstack/oneinstack;./backup.sh >> /data/back.log 2>&1 &
```

then it looks like this:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
0 1 * * * cd /opt/oneinstack/oneinstack;./backup.sh >> /data/back.log 2>&1 &
```

In addition:
Like @Ugur mentioned, it is unnecessary to cd, if you take care of the paths correctly in the `backup.sh` . For example:

```
ROOTPATH="/path/to/data"
TARTGETPATH="/path/to/target"
FileToBackup="${ROOTPATH}/myfile"

rsync $FileToBackup $TARGETPATH/
```

Comment: thanks, for me `SHELL=/bin/bash` worked perfectly .